# Psr-4 Laravel Namespace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespace

estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.1 en una app que ya se encuentra funcionando, pero estoy cambiando de a modulos al patrón repositorio.

```
"psr-4": {
    "app\\": "app/",
    "Cms\\": "app/cms"
}
```

La primera es el namespace por defecto y la segunda es lo que estoy cambiando y pasando a dicha carpeta. Cuando llamo a un controlador dentro de app/cms me tira el siguiente error :

> Class app\Http\Controllers\CalendarioController does not exist

Es como que nunca busca en app\cms.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Calendario'], function() {
       Route::resource('calendario', 'CalendarioController');
});
```

y el namespace del controllador como:

```
namespace Cms\Calendario;
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque no sé como está tu RouteServiceProvider, lo más probable es que con el código que muestras del grupo de rutas estás agregando un segundo namespace al que ya existe en RouteServiceProvider.

La forma correcta según la documentación de Laravel sería agregar otro namespace en RouteServiceProvider y preferiblemente otro archivo de rutas (tal y como se hace en Laravel 5.3):

```
<?php

namespace app\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $namespace = 'app\Http\Controllers';

    protected $cmsNamespace = 'app\cms\Http\Controllers';


    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        //

        parent::boot($router);
    }

    public function map(Router $router)
    {

        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });


        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->cmsNamespace], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/routes.cms.php');
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Recien veo tu respuesta y me viene perfecto!

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió, puedes considerar aceptarla. Gracias.

Comment: Aceptarla te referís a usarla o tengo que hacer algo? ... recién estoy empezando acá. Te puse flechita para arriba

Comment: Me refiero a que hay un símbolo de "check" al lado de las flechitas precisamente, haz clic en dicho símbolo para aceptarla.

Comment: Esta bien, disculpa. Muchas gracias!